# SSH: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, 17.04

SSH connection has been working properly, but today unfortunately it stopped.

I had lots of tries to solve it.

> > > linux@mylinux:~$ ssh root@XX.XX.XXX.XXX 
> > >       ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection refused
> > >
> > > linux@mylinux:~$ ssh root@XX.XX.XXX.XXX -p 8787 
> > >       ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XXX.XXX port 8787: Connection refused

```
>>>linux@mylinux:~$ ssh root@XX.XX.XXX.XXX -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "XX.XX.XXX.XXX" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XX.XX.XXX.XXX [XX.XX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address XX.XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection refused

ssh - status

>● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-11-18 15:42:28 IST; 31min ago
 Main PID: 6940 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─6940 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Also, I have removed `openssh-sever` and reinstalled it, but it can not succeed.

When I try to connect via localhost then it is a success, but on a remote site it is refused.

But I still can not succeed.

Why is my SSH connection refused?

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Host *

*#    $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

*# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
*# sshd_config(5) for more information.

*# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

*# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
*# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
*# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
*# default value.

*#Port 22
*#AddressFamily any
*#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
*#ListenAddress ::

*#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
*#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
*#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

*# Ciphers and keying
*#RekeyLimit default none

*# Logging
*#SyslogFacility AUTH
*#LogLevel INFO

*# Authentication:

*#LoginGraceTime 2m
*#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
*#StrictModes yes
*#MaxAuthTries 6
*#MaxSessions 10

*#PubkeyAuthentication yes

*# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
*#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

*#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

*#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
*#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

*# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
*#HostbasedAuthentication no
*# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
*# HostbasedAuthentication
*#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
*# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
*#IgnoreRhosts yes

*# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
*#PasswordAuthentication yes
*#PermitEmptyPasswords no

*# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
*# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

*# Kerberos options
*#KerberosAuthentication no
*#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
*#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
*#KerberosGetAFSToken no

*# GSSAPI options
*#GSSAPIAuthentication no
*#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
*#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
*#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

*# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
*# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
*# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
*# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
*# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
*# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
*# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
*# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
*# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

*#AllowAgentForwarding yes
*#AllowTcpForwarding yes
*#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
*#X11DisplayOffset 10
*#X11UseLocalhost yes
*#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
*#PrintLastLog yes
*#TCPKeepAlive yes
*#UseLogin no
*#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
*#PermitUserEnvironment no
*#Compression delayed
*#ClientAliveInterval 0
*#ClientAliveCountMax 3
*#UseDNS no
*#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
*#MaxStartups 10:30:100
*#PermitTunnel no
*#ChrootDirectory none
*#VersionAddendum none

*# no default banner path
*#Banner none

*# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

*# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem    sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

*# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
*#Match User anoncvs
*#    X11Forwarding no
*#    AllowTcpForwarding no
*#    PermitTTY no
*#    ForceCommand cvs server
```

**Here**

> > > sudo netstat -tlpena | grep -i "ssh"

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25237      1260/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          25239      1260/sshd
```

**AND**

> > > sudo iptables -S

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is SSH service listening on the ports you're trying to connect? perhaps iptables problem? Are you allowed to log in as root?

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking access? Have you verified that sshd is running on remote end? This is the two most likely answers.

Comment: lol @vidarlo :)

Comment: @vidarlo yeah there is firewall but i do not there is blocking access or not

Comment: Edit your question with output of `iptables -S` && `netstat -tlpnea` , also post your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: try `ssh localhost` on the machine you want to login to.  if it can't; then its likely sshd (openssh-server) isn't running as already suggested...

Comment: @fugitive yeah i have access via console

Comment: @guiverc ssh localhost activate but remote is not working

Comment: @fugitive wait a bit i will edit

Comment: this is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Post `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @fugitive sorry i will

Comment: @fugitive i have Post /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: `ssh localhost` is to be done on the machine you want to login to (ie. server & NOT your 'mylinux' host).  if the host/server can't ssh into itself; no other machine is going to be able to.

Comment: Install nmap on the system you try to connect from. Then make a port scan of the system you try to connect to, like so. 'nmap -sS <IPtoConnectTo>'. Post your findings here...

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `sshd` config with:

```
Port 22
PermitRootLogin yes
```

and restart sshd service. Also, not sure why your lines starts with `*`, is that a formatting issue?
If there are `*` on `sshd` config please do `sed -i 's/^*//g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: yeah there is formatting issue so i put "*"

Comment: not working!!!!!!again Connection refused

Comment: Have you done a restart of `sshd` to apply changes? Please show output of `iptables -S` and `netstat -tlpena`

Comment: yes i do that!!!!!!!!

Comment: ok i will do wait a bit

Comment: PermitRootLogin no would not lead to connectoin refused. Connection refused happens because nothing is listening, or a firewall somewhere in the path stops the connection.

Comment: there is no firewall stops connection cause that's can not be active..please help

Comment: when ssh-copy-id -n 45.55.XXX.XXX
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host 45.55.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your firewall is blocking the connection. Try to shortly disable it to make sure.

Specifically, on INPUT (irrelevant parts removed) :

You first go to "ufw-before-input"

```
-P INPUT DROP
...
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
```

From there you go to "ufw-not-local"

```
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
```

Which DROPs anything that isn't "LOCAL", "MULTICAST" or "BROADCAST"

```
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
```

So your

```
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

seems to come too late